# Wrong output in Project Euler

Tags: c++

**Project Euler #8:**

The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.

```
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
```

Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

**Question:**
I have built this program and it seems to run exactly how I want it to, but it outputs the wrong answer and I'm not sure why (2091059712). I realise printing all the values out every time probably isn't the most elegant way of running it but I couldn't think of any other way to check if the numbers were right.

Please help...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i0, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9, i10, i11, i12;
    long product = 0;
    long newProd = 0;

    char thou[] = "731671765313306249192251196744265747423553491949349698352032774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

    int length = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 13; i++) {
        i0 = thou[i] - '0';
        printf("i0: %d\n", i0);
        i1 = thou[i + 1] - '0';
        printf("i1: %d\n", i1);

        i2 = thou[i + 2] - '0';
        printf("i2: %d\n", i2);

        i3 = thou[i + 3] - '0';
        printf("i3: %d\n", i3);

        i4 = thou[i + 4] - '0';
        printf("i4: %d\n", i4);

        i5 = thou[i + 5] - '0';
        printf("i5: %d\n", i5);

        i6 = thou[i + 6] - '0';
        printf("i6: %d\n", i6);

        i7 = thou[i + 7] - '0';
        printf("i7: %d\n", i7);

        i8 = thou[i + 8] - '0';
        printf("i8: %d\n", i8);

        i9 = thou[i + 9] - '0';
        printf("i9: %d\n", i9);

        i10 = thou[i + 10] - '0';
        printf("i10: %d\n", i10);

        i11 = thou[i + 11] - '0';
        printf("i11: %d\n", i11);

        i12 = thou[i + 12] - '0';
        printf("i12: %d\n", i12);

        newProd = i0 * i1 * i2 * i3 * i4 * i5 * i6 * i7 * i8 * i9 * i10 * i11 * i12;
        printf("\nnewProd: %ld\n\n", newProd);
        if (newProd > product) {
            product = newProd;
            printf("*****************************************\n\n");
        }
    }
    printf("answer: %ld\n", product);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Done Guy Incognito

Comment: What is the correct output supposed to be?

Comment: What do you expect the answer to be? Does that answer fit inside a 32-bit signed integer?

Comment: Changing your data types to `int64_t` gives the answer `23514624000`

Comment: I expected the answer to be 23514624000 as Alan said. What is the difference between `int64_t` and `long`, and why didn't `long` work in this situation?

Comment: also, even when I use `long long`, it still comes up with same error saying I can't cast an 8 byte value onto a 4 byte value, but I though `long long` was an 8 byte data type (I am still very new to coding)